# Check the block connected that an item frame is connected to

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to check the inventory of a hopper that has an item frame connecting to it, however I can't even get it to say "hi". I currently have this:

```
execute as @e[type=minecraft:item_frame,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:iron_ingot"},Facing:5b}] run execute if data block ~-1 ~ ~ minecraft:hopper run say Hi
```

If I run the following it says "hi":

```
execute as @e[type=minecraft:item_frame,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:iron_ingot"},Facing:5b}] run say hi
```

so I know it's targeting the item frame. The item frame is facing west so I minus 1 from the x to try to get the hopper but then nothing runs.

Answer (score 2):

I had to change the command from execute as to execute at

```
execute at @e[type=minecraft:item_frame,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:iron_ingot"},Facing:5b}] run execute if data block ~-1 ~ ~ minecraft:hopper run say Hi
```

Answer (score 2):

Command that works regardless of the direction of the item frame:

```
execute as @e[type=minecraft:item_frame,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:iron_ingot"}}] at @s if block ^ ^ ^-1 minecraft:hopper run say hi
```

Comment: Omg thanks for sharing this. This will cut my code right down